# Prefetch Without Direct Relation Django

Tags: python, sql, django

In Django is there a way to do a prefetch without having a direct foreign key relationship?

Or specifically, to do a prefetch based off the values of two columns?

I have the models

```
class ProductionType(models.Model  ):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="New Job Progress Type")
    def __str__(self):
        return  self.name
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "{0}".format(obj.name)

class ProductionRecord(models.Model):

    job = models.ForeignKey(Job,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,related_name="production_records")
    type = models.ForeignKey(ProductionType,null=True)
    done = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

and then in another app

```
class ShopProgress(models.Model  ):

    job= models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="shop_progress")
    total=models.IntegerField(null=True)
    type=models.ForeignKey(ProductionType,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def done(self):

        x = ProductionRecord.objects.values_list("done").filter(job=self.job, type=self.type).aggregate(models.Sum('done'))
        t =x["done__sum"]
        if t == None or t== 0:
            t=0
        self._done=t
        return t
```

ProductionRecord and ShopProgress both reference a Job and a Production Type.
So the relation is dependent on these two fields, not a direct foreign key.

In this particular case, i would like for the query in "ShopProgress.done()" to be prefetched when querying ShopProgress.

A similar raw query would look roughly like

```
select a.id, a.type_id, a.total ,sum(b.done), a.job_id from DailyProgressReport_shopprogress a
left join production_productionrecord b on b.type_id=a.type_id and b.job_id = a.job_id
group by a.job_id, a.type_id
order by a.id
```

I hope the question is concise. If not, let me know and i will try to provide additional clarity.